# Complex Mongodb aggregation, add new calculated fields to current docs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I want to get some values with calculation.

Sample documents:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90524"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90525"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90526"),
    "field": "z",
    "values": 1
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90527"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90528"),
    "field": "z",
    "values": 1
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90529"),
    "field": "y",
    "values": 1
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90524"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90525"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90526"),
    "field": "z",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90527"),
    "field": "x",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90528"),
    "field": "z",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}{
    "_id": ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90529"),
    "field": "y",
    "values": 1,
    "sum": 6
}
```

I want to calculate sum of all "values" field and add this value to as "sum" fields to all documents. How can I do it ? I tried $group operation, with $group operation, I am getting only one document.

I am trying to get all documents with calculated values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        "sum": {
          $sum: "$values",
          "window": {
            "documents": ["unbounded","unbounded"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/92X9uhFKtcg)

Comment: If you have `["unbounded","unbounded"]` then you can skip `window` entirely.

Comment: But mine mongodb verison is not 5 (4.4) and this operator doesnt exist in 4.4 verison

Comment: @reis12341 see is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tXQj9ucNm3K) works for you.